# Adding datetime to ipywidgets in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, datetimepicker, ipywidgets

I know that ipywidgets have a datepicker widget and its pretty cool. However, I'm hoping I can also pick the time for that date. I haven't been able to see in the ipywidgets documentation an option to do that. I found a library called ipydatetime, here's the documentation (https://ipydatetime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/introduction.html) that in theory should do the trick but it doesn't even show up when I create the widget in jupyter notebooks.

Any help would be highly appreaciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors when trying to show the widget? have you followed all steps of the installation instructions? https://ipydatetime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: Missing from the install instructions is (for jupyterlab 2): `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@2.0`

Comment: You will also need nodejs installed for this. See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html#installing-into-jupyterlab-1-or-2 for more instrunctions on getting owrking widgets in jupyter

Comment: No I haven't gotten any errors, I tried installing nodejs and still isn't working. My current environment is jupyterhub so I don't know if I need jupyter lab manager.

Comment: I'm using google collab and I cant't see the control. I installed the jupyter line code too but It doesn't show anything.